Python: map json format with names in another list
I have a table.json file like this:
  {
    "tables": 
    [
        {
            "name": "table_1",
            "columns": 
            {
                "column1": "name",
                "column2": "address"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "table_2",
            "columns": 
            {
                "column1": "name",
                "column2": "address"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "table_3",
            "columns": 
            {
                "column1": "name",
                "column2": "address"
            }
        }
    ]
}

I can write successfully into Python like this:
try:
        with open('table.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            mapping_data = json.load(f)
            table_mappings = {table['name']: {'columns': table['columns']} for table in mapping_data.get('tables', [])}
            print(table_mappings)
except Exception as e:
        print(f"error: {str(e)}\n")

Now I have three tables with random names, let's say like 'abc','rfe' and 'try'. They all have same column names, so I decide to rewrite my json file without table names and map them afterwards:
new_table.json:
  {
    "tables": 
    [
        {
            "columns": 
            {
                "column1": "name",
                "column2": "address"
            }
        }
    ]
}

How can I map them with names from a list and columns from json?
table_list=['abc','rfe','try']
table_mappings = {for i in table_list: {'columns': table['columns']} for table in mapping_data.get('tables', [])}


you can modify your codelike this:
import json

table_list = ['abc', 'rfe', 'try']

try:
    with open('new_table.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        mapping_data = json.load(f)
        table_mappings = {table_name: {'columns': mapping_data['tables'][0]['columns']} for table_name in table_list}
        print(table_mappings)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"error: {str(e)}\n")

